# Hadoop Mapreduce: TextInputFormat: Meaning of position

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to understand the doc which says "The TextInputFormat works as An InputFormat for plain text files. Files are broken into lines. Either linefeed or carriage-return are used to signal end of line. **Keys are the position** in the file, and values are the line of text"

What does "position" mean? does it mean the line number in the file?

Given data in a file

```
  dobbs   2007      20      18     15
  dobbs   2008      22      20     12
  doctor  2007  545525  366136  57313
  doctor  2008  668666  446034  72694
```

Would it produce a map input like this?

```
  (1,  "dobbs   2007    20  18  15")
  (2,  "dobbs   2008    22  20  12")
  (3,  "doctor  2007    545525  366136  57313")
  (4,  "doctor  2008    668666  446034  72694")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TextInputFormat, Keys are the `byte offset` in the file from the beginning of the file to the `line`

i.e., for the first line, offset or key will be `0`
for the second line the offset or key will be `length of first line` 
 for the third line offset will be `offset of first line + length of first line`

No, it will not produce map input as you expects,
**(assuming each word is separated by single space)** it would rather be something like

```
(0,dobbs 2007 20 18 15)
(20,dobbs 2008 22 20 12)
(40,doctor 2007 545525 366136 57313)
(71,doctor 2008 668666 446034 72694)
```

Comment: Vishnu, Thank you so much for the answer. That's exactly what I am looking for. Very much appreciate your help!